# How to NAT host-bit to host-bit between two networks in python

Tags: python, networking, ip-address, python-ipaddress

I'm trying to figure out the best way to perform a host-bit to host-bit NAT translation in python. For example:

```py
from ipaddress import IPv4Address

# We have some IPs in the 192.168.0.0/26 and 172.31.0.0/27 networks
IPv4Address('192.168.0.15') # /26 net prefix length
IPv4Address('172.31.0.26') # /27 net prefix length

# We need to translate them to their new respective NAT IPs
# in the 10.15.0.0/26, 10.15.0.0/27 networks,
# but matching original host bits (.15, .26)
IPv4Address('10.15.0.15') # /26 net prefix length
IPv4Address('10.15.0.26') # /27 net prefix length
```

In my use case, let's assume that the original network and NAT network prefix lengths will always match each other (whether that is /16,/24 /28, etc). How would I programmatically calculate the host bits of some original IP and map it to its corresponding NAT IP as a `IPv4Address` object?

Please let me know if any other info is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Just copy the low-order 32-n bits of the address, where n is the prefix length.

Comment: Note that NAT doesn't usually use 1-to-1 mapping like this. Normally everything behind the router is mapped to the router's public IP, and port numbers are used to determine which private IP each connection goes to.

Comment: @Barmar, basic NAT does a one-to-one translation. It is the NAPT (Network Address Port Translation) variant of NAT the does what you describe. _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2663.html)_ explains it.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. This NAT scenario is slightly unique where two overlapping networks (VPCs) need to communicate with each other in AWS. Connections are initiated bidirectionally between these two networks over the same device, so port-address trans won't work.

Comment: @RonMaupin Technically true, but most uses of NAT in the real world are actually NAPT. The main reason for NAT is because there aren't enough public addresses, so NAT allows 1 public address to proxy for many private addresses. If you have enough addresses to do a 1-to-1 mapping, you might as well just use those addresses directly instead of NAT.

Comment: The biggest use of NAT I run into is when companies merge or acquired, and they have overlapping addresses. You use a one-to-one outside source NAT to connect the networks until one or both sides can be readdressed, and that can take a few years. The NAPT variant is what was put into place for the reasons you describe, but NAT existed for other reasons prior to that.